# Not accessing the value using between statement in sql

Tags: sql, date, varchar, between

I am storing the date as varchar in database. When I am trying to access some data using `between` operator in sql, to get some values between certain dates, it is not giving proper output because I stored the date as varchar. The date is in this format `(01/12/2013)(dd/mm/yyyy)`.

Any idea to access the correct data using between statement with out changing the date from varchar to date format?

Thank you.

Comment: You can at least use to_date in where clause...

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused about the datatype - it has nothing to do with your problem. You see this if you remove the / in the dates - to get real numbers: 20/02/2013 is actually more than 21 million higher than 01/02/2014

20/02/2013 = 20022013
 
01/02/2014 =  1022014

If your varchar has the numbers in the order of date, month, year - you must reorder them in the field or in the query to get the correct values, but if they are in year month day, you have a varchar that will sort just like a datetime.

**SOLUTION 1:**
If you must leave it the way it is in the table, you must do this:

Database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `dates` (
  `date_varchar` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Data:

```
date_varchar  date_datetime        
01/02/2013    2013-02-01 00:00:00  
02/02/2013    2013-02-02 00:00:00  
03/02/2013    2013-02-03 00:00:00  
03/02/2014    2014-02-03 00:00:00  
03/03/2013    2013-03-03 00:00:00  
04/02/2013    2013-02-04 00:00:00  
05/02/2013    2013-02-05 00:00:00
```

The query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dates 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_varchar,'%d/%m/%Y') 
BETWEEN '2013-02-03' AND  '2013-02-04'
```

Will return two records:

```
date_varchar  date_datetime        
03/02/2013    2013-02-03 00:00:00  
04/02/2013    2013-02-04 00:00:00
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

To change the order in the varchar to year, month, date in the field. Se the table data below:

```
date_varchar  date_datetime        
2013/02/01    2013-02-01 00:00:00  
2013/02/02    2013-02-02 00:00:00  
2013/02/03    2013-02-03 00:00:00  
2013/02/04    2013-02-04 00:00:00  
2013/02/05    2013-02-05 00:00:00  
2013/03/03    2013-03-03 00:00:00  
2014/02/03    2014-02-03 00:00:00
```

Now you can select :

```
SELECT * 
FROM dates 
WHERE date_varchar 
BETWEEN '2013/02/02' AND '2013/02/03'
```

Now the numbers are ordered in the same way as datetime - you can just remove the / and - to see the numbers. So varchars are sorted the same as date_time

The query return the same two rows:

```
date_varchar  date_datetime        
2013/02/02    2013-02-02 00:00:00  
2013/02/03    2013-02-03 00:00:00
```

**SOLUTION 3:**

This is not for you, because you don't want to change the table, but i include it to make this complete. By changing the datatype to datetime you are forced to put the numbers in correct order and you use this query to get a range between dates:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dates 
WHERE date_datetime 
BETWEEN '2013-02-03' AND  '2013-02-04'
```

The same two record:

```
date_varchar  date_datetime        
03/02/2013    2013-02-03 00:00:00  
04/02/2013    2013-02-04 00:00:00
```

**EXAMPLE OF THE PROBLEM:**

Now just selecting the dates as varchar returns - you guessed it - the very same two records like first query **and some more**, just like what is happening to you:

Data:

```
date_varchar  date_datetime        
01/02/2013    2013-02-01 00:00:00  
02/02/2013    2013-02-02 00:00:00  
03/02/2013    2013-02-03 00:00:00  
03/02/2014    2014-02-03 00:00:00  
03/03/2013    2013-03-03 00:00:00  
04/02/2013    2013-02-04 00:00:00  
05/02/2013    2013-02-05 00:00:00

SELECT * 
FROM dates 
WHERE date_varchar 
BETWEEN '03/02/2013' AND  '04/02/2013'

date_varchar  date_datetime        
03/02/2013    2013-02-05 00:00:00  
03/02/2014    2014-02-03 00:00:00  
03/03/2013    2013-02-05 00:00:00  
04/02/2013    2013-02-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: Your last query would also return e.g. '03/03/2013' and '03/02/2014' if found in the table.

Answer (score 0):

you are storing date as varchar then use to_date function to convert into date format then use between operator:

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE to_date(order_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') between to_date ('01/12/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND to_date ('31/12/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you use MS SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,order_date,101) between CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/12/2012',101)
AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'31/12/2012',101);
```

Answer (score 0):

just write following query

```
select * 
from table 
where str_to_date('01/01/2013','%m%d%Y') between '2012-01-02' and '2013-01-02'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to look for solution without changing the data format if I am not wrong. 
Between operator cannot understand that data is date if it not explicitly mentioned. So you have to say that this field is date. There are similar functions in every database like date(), to_date(). As I am not aware which database you are using, I cannot give you exact syntax of how to resolve it. 
But I am sure that you can find it easily. Let me know if need more details.